# Test causing error occasionally

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have really weird issue when running a Selenium Webdriver test.

My code

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'/problematic_url')]")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.className("green_true")).click();
```

The elements actually exist. I can even see that the problematic url is clicked by the webdriver, but then nothing happens. Browser won't go the page and won't find green_true element. Error is caused. But only occasionally. Sometimes test runs as it should.

Can anyone tell how can this be?

I cannot use exact urls, because they vary according to selected language.

Answer (score 0):

well. would suggest to modify in the following way:
instead of

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'/problematic_url')]")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.className("green_true")).click();
```

try use following:

```
public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        WebElement foo = wait.until(
new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return driver.findElement(locator);
                }
                }
);
                           return  foo;              }     ;

fluentWait(By.id("id")).click();
fluentWait(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'/problematic_url')]")).click();
fluentWait(By.className("green_true")).click();
```

The problem can be that you prolly get some AJAX on the page after interacting with elements(clicking, etc).  IMHO we need to use a lil bit more robust wait mechanism.

a piece of advice: when you got xpath for webelement or css selector do not forget to verify found locators in fireBug, ffox extension.
[image: locators verify]
Regards.

Comment: Same problem still occures. Since the test passes usually on first run, could it have something to do with driver initialization?

Comment: could you provide the source for exception you get?

Comment: The error i get is Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"green_true"}

Comment: verify carefully that you found WebElement properly. http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/    -
here is nice manual for xpath, css,  DOM

Comment: for me it seems that it can be one of the problems: either locator is not correct or selenium is trying to interact with element which are still not on the page for some reasons: long response for server.
In my opinion if all locators are correct and firebug approves it, other possible pronlems should be handled by fluent wait

Answer (score 0):

try to use an explicit wait when clicking on a dynamic element. Wait until the elements appear on the web browser or the actions are applied on them. You can use this pattern :

```
final FluentWait<WebDriver> wait =
            new FluentWait<WebDriver>(getDriver())
                    .withTimeout(MASK_PRESENCE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .pollingEvery(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
                    .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
                    .withMessage("Time out while waiting the element is loaded");

    wait.until(new Predicate<WebDriver>() {

        @Override
        public boolean apply(final WebDriver driver) {
            return ! driver.findElements(By.id("id")).isEmpty(); 
        }

    });
```