# Is the fluent webdriver initialized right?

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver

This is kinda follow-up for my question [Test causing error occasionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911244/test-causing-error-occasionally). I initialize my driver

```
public class TestSuite {

public static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

}


public class FluentDriver extends TestSuite {

public static WebElement fluentWait(final By locator) {
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    WebElement element = wait.until(
            new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {

                public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return driver.findElement(locator);
                }
            });
    return element;
}
```

;
}

But this this not handling the script which certainly is on the page, but I can't access the source of it.

```
    FluentDriver.fluentWait(By.id("id")).click();
    FluentDriver.fluentWait(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'/problematic_url.html')]")).click();
    FluentDriver.fluentWait(By.className("green_true")).click();
```

Clicking the "id" pulls out a submenu, where the problematic url is. On webpage source (Ctrl+U) the url is present the whole time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by adding Javascript enabling Firefox profile on driver. Then I use the FluentDriver solution. It works most of the time.